# Allowing content updates with a user level token secret

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to allow for a document to be updated via the firebase restful API with a token that I generate on creation of that document which is then made available to the creator of that content. **The document can be read by all users, but only updated by users who supply the write token** I can't quite work out all the details in my mind. So...

1. A user (of my firebase app) creates content at `documents/-Kfhcn34324bfjdskj2`
2. As part of the creation process of that document, a token gets generated and stored.. perhaps in `documents/-Kfhcn34324bfjdskj2/secrets`
3. A PATCH request can now be made by the owner of `-Kfhcn34324bfjdskj2` as they can view the contents of `secrets`, get the token, and hit a url that looks like this...

`name.firebaseapp.com/documents/-Kfhcn34324bfjdskj2.json?token=hfjskdhfsdhfj23h4234234324j324kh`

Any user can still hit..

`name.firebaseapp.com/documents/-Kfhcn34324bfjdskj2.json`

..and read this document.

The root of my question revolves around this basic token auth process. Is this possible?

Comment: I've done such a "shared secret" approach before, so it is definitely possible. Essentially you should allow only the owner of a document to create a secret and then only allow uploading of data to that secret location.  It all hangs on writing the right [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/). Have a go at it and report back here if you get stuck.

Comment: The part where I'm stuck is how to pass the secret to firebase. I could include the secret in the data payload and check it's value via the `newData` predefined var, but then the secret will be stored with the data where other users can read it. I didn't find any info in the security rules about accessing the query params on a url (like if i was to include the secret as `?secret=`).

Comment: The key to such a secret is to allow anyone to write a new secert, but only allow to read a secret if you know it. So: `"secrets": { ".write": true, ".read": false, "$secret": { ".read": true }}`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I realized I didn't quite word this question correctly, updated for clarity!